# clustering with limited maximum size

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I want to cluster some data points but the maximum number of points per cluster is limited. So there is a maximum size per cluster. Is there any clustering algorithm for that? 
Also Can I define my own size function. For example, instead of considering the number of points in a cluster as its size, I want to sum a column of all the points in the cluster.

Comment: This is a paper I found: http://users.cs.fiu.edu/~taoli/pub/clustering-size-constraint.pdf

Answer (score 1):

A quick and not a optimal solution is spliting data into 2 parts iteratively until the number of data is under the limitation.

Answer (score 1):

The problem of k-means clustering with **minimum size** constraints is addressed in this paper:

Bradley, P. S., K. P. Bennett, and Ayhan Demiriz. "Constrained k-means clustering." *Microsoft Research, Redmond (2000)*: 1-8.

However, the approach proposed in this paper can be easily extended to the **maximum size** constraints.

[Here](https://github.com/Behrouz-Babaki/MinSizeKmeans) is an implementation of this algorithm and an extension to it which addresses both *minimum size* and *maximum size* constraints.

AS for your question about custom size function, it will be a more difficult problem for which I guess local search approaches are more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

As clustering will usually try to make the clusters as large as possible, this isn't really clustering then anymore. More like a minimum spanning tree, where you remove the longest edges to find groups.

You could try something like x-means, i.e. a k-means variation where you split clusters that you consider to be too large.